# Javascript variable scroll issue

Tags: javascript

I have a page whereby the user can press left + right buttons to scroll through numbers between 1-10.

The default value is 0 which displays blank.

There are two buttons at the bottom which allow the user to 'Clear' the number - reseting it to 0. Or to 'Shuffle', picking a random number.

After this the user can submit these numbers into a database.

My issue is, if the user were to scroll to 5 (for example), click shuffle then submit, it would submit '5' instead of the random number it should have generated.

Also if the user only clicks 'shuffle' then submit, it'll input '0'.

The issue with the 'clear' button is similar, if the user scrolls to 5, then hits reset, the variable would stay at '5' when submitted.

I'm probably overcomplicating something very simple, and im sorry if i am, but this is annoying me.

Thankyou ~

Comment: You have to show us some code.  There is no way to help you otherwise.

Comment: Can you maybe post your code so that it will be possible to see what's wrong with it?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong:
There are 3 buttons, submit, reset, and shuffle.
They are below a text field which contains the number 0 initially. When they press left or right, the number increase/decreases.
When they press reset, the number becomes 0 again.
When they press shuffle, the number becomes a random number.
When they press submit, the number is sent to a DB.
Is all of that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what the problem is without looking at your code. I get the feeling it is something like this:

Javascript

```
var opNumb = 0; //default number

left = function(){if (opNumb>0) opNumb--;
                      updateNumb(opNumb);}
right = function(){if (opNumb<10) opNumb++;
                      updateNumb(opNumb);}

def = function(){opNumb=0;
                 updateNumb(opNumb);} //function to return to default

randomNumb = function(){opNumb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
                        updateNumb(opNumb);} 

updateNumb = function(Numb){document.forms[0].opVal.value = Numb;}
window.onkeydown = press;            //bind keydown to press function

function press(e){
if (e.keyCode == 37) left(); 
if (e.keyCode == 39) right() 
    }
```

HTML form

```
<form id="frm1">
<input type="text" name="opVal" value="0"/><br />
<input type="button" value="left" onclick="left()"/><input type="button" value="right" onclick="right()"/><input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="def()"/><input type="button" value="Shuffle" onclick="randomNumb()"/><br />
<input type="button" value="Submit form" onclick="alert(opNumb);"/>
</form>​
```

What does your form look like? You're most likely having a problem setting a value?

[Link to example](http://jsfiddle.net/biped/RrrQM/13/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your number isn't saving so whenever you update the number on the screen I would save the number then that way you should always be sending the number that you see.

```
var number = 0;
//All your events to call the different functions

function moveLeft{
  //logic
  reset(num);
}
function moveRight{
  //logic
  reset(num);
}
function shuffle{
  //logic
  reset(num);
}
function reset{
  //logic
  reset(num);
}

reset(num){
  number = num;
  //update the HTML
}
```